# Cannot login to Ubuntu after changing home directory

Tags: passwd, passwd-file

I recently tried changing my home directory from `/home/henry` to `/hdd/home/henry` using `viwp passwd`.

/hdd is a separate hard drive.

I then rebooted the system but I cannot log in.  I get the login screen, but when I enter my password it simply returns to the login screen

What do I do?

Comment: Did you edit fstab with the new path to home?

Comment: It's likely still possible to login to a CLI session on one of the virtual terminals (CTRL+ALT+F2 etc.), although it will dump you into / if it can't open your home

Answer (score 2):

You should reboot in rescue mode (see https://www.linuxtechi.com/boot-ubuntu-20-04-rescue-emergency-mode/).
There you change it back to what it was and then change it using:

```
usermod -d /hdd/home/henry henry
```

Comment: I cannot use this because I'm logged in as henry

Comment: But booting into rescue environment should let you log in as root.